# Only displaying some legend contents

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am interested in displaying only the top 3 most abundant groups in my ggplot2 legend.

for example, in this table, i have 7 groups and i would only like to display groups D, E, F in my ggplot2 legend

| group | sample size |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 25 |
| E | 23 |
| F | 20 |
| G | 3 |

I tried searching online but the closest answers i got was to reorder the legend.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Mel

Comment: What kind of plot are you trying to do? With the data you provided it is not clear where a legend should be of need.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show the code you tried.

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve this by setting the categories to show up in the legend via the `breaks` argument of `scale_fill_discrete`:

```r
df <- data.frame(
             group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
       sample.size = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 25L, 23L, 20L, 3L)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

top_group <- df %>% top_n(3, sample.size) %>% pull(group)

ggplot(df, aes(group, sample.size, fill = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = top_group)
```

[image]

**EDIT** In case of `scale_fill_manual` one option would be to name your list of colors. This has the additional benefit that you could assign colors to names or Categories without bothering about the order in which you pass the colors to the `values` argument of the scale:

```r
# Example color palette
colourslist <- scales::hue_pal()(length(unique(df$group)))
# Name your list of colors
names(colourslist) <- unique(df$group)

ggplot(df, aes("1", sample.size, fill = group)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color="darkgrey") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colourslist, breaks = top_group) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: This probably answers part of the question (upvote), but it manually does the "displaying only the top 3 most abundant groups". You might want to annotate each row with a new column to highlight those 3 most abundant groups, then use the `scale_colour_manual()`

Comment: I'm sure you know that instead of painstakingly spelling out `c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")`, you could also write `LETTERS[1:7]` ... ;)

Comment: @tjebo Thank god,`datapasta` did the job for me. :D

Comment: Cannot believe I didn't know this one till now :D

Comment: @tjebo Haha, yeah, I don't use it that often, but `datapasta` is good to know if you have to copy & paste data (quickly) from a PDF or an XL or from an HTML table.

Comment: @stefan, Thank you so much! I am currently using scale_fill_manual() where i specified the colours I am interested in (saved in colourslist). The breaks option does not work as i would like. When I use the breaks option, only the items in my list has colour and the rest is grey.

top.list<- c( "Ambassis kopsii","Gerres oyena", "Monacanthus chinensis")


ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=n, fill=Host))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity",color="darkgrey")+
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colourslist, breaks=top.list)

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Melissa. Without a look at your colourslist I could only guess. My guess is that you simply pass a vector of colors which gives me grey bars too. To fix this issue you could name your colorlist. One option to fix this would be to name the colourslist. See my edit.

Comment: Hello @stefan, thank you so much! I managed to plot what I was looking for.